# Error on hybris for daos-services

Tags: spring-boot, dao, sap-commerce-cloud, facade

this is error:

> WARN  [localhost-startStop-1] [CloseAwareApplicationContext] Exception
>   encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh
>   attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'totalCustomersDao' defined in class
>   path resource [trainingcore-spring.xml]: Error setting property
>   values; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'modelService' of bean class
>   [de.hybris.training.core.dao.impl.TotalCustomersDaoImpl]: Bean
>   property 'modelService' is not writable or has an invalid setter
>   method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of
>   the getter?         WARN  [localhost-startStop-1]
>   [CloseAwareApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context
>   initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'totalCustomersDao' defined in class path
>   resource [trainingcore-spring.xml]: Error setting property values;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'modelService' of bean class
>   [de.hybris.training.core.dao.impl.TotalCustomersDaoImpl]: Bean
>   property 'modelService' is not writable or has an invalid setter
>   method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of
>   the getter?         ERROR [localhost-startStop-1]
>   [HybrisContextFactory] Error initializing global application context! 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'totalCustomersDao' defined in class path
>   resource [trainingcore-spring.xml]: Error setting property values;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'modelService' of bean class
>   [de.hybris.training.core.dao.impl.TotalCustomersDaoImpl]: Bean
>   property 'modelService' is not writable or has an invalid setter
>   method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of
>   the getter?

**trainingcore.spring.xml**

```
<!-- Total Customer service dao facade-->

<alias alias="totalCustomersDao" name="totalCustomersDao"/>
<bean id="totalCustomersDao"
      class="de.hybris.training.core.dao.impl.TotalCustomersDaoImpl"
      parent="abstractItemDao" >
    <property name="flexibleSearchService" ref="flexibleSearchService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="totalCustomerService"
      class=" de.hybris.training.core.impl.TotalCustomerServiceImpl" >
    <property name="totalCustomersDao" ref="totalCustomersDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="totalCustomerFacade" class="de.hybris.training.core.facade.impl.TotalCustomerFacadeImpl">
    <property name="totalCustomerService" ref="totalCustomerService"/>
</bean>
```

**TotalCustomersDaoImpl**

```
public class TotalCustomersDaoImpl implements TotalCustomersDao { private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOG = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(UsersFindJob.class);

    private static final String query =
            "SELECT *" +
            "FROM {" + CustomerModel._TYPECODE + "}"+
            "WHERE p_name  LIKE "
                    + "'%" + CustomerModel.NAME+"+%'";


    private DefaultFlexibleSearchService flexibleSearchService;

    public List<CustomerModel> findAllCustomersFromDao(String name) {

        LOG.info("***********************************");
        LOG.info("***********************************");
        LOG.info("*************************findAllCustomersFromDao**********");
        LOG.info("***********************************");
        LOG.info("***********************************");

        final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put(CustomerModel.NAME, name);

        FlexibleSearchQuery fQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(query);
        if (params != null) {
            fQuery.addQueryParameters(params);
        }

        final SearchResult<CustomerModel> result = flexibleSearchService.search(fQuery);
        return result.getResult();
    }


    public void setFlexibleSearchService(DefaultFlexibleSearchService flexibleSearchService) {
        this.flexibleSearchService = flexibleSearchService;
    }

    public DefaultFlexibleSearchService getFlexibleSearchService() {
        return flexibleSearchService;
    }

}
```

**TotalCustomerFacadeImpl**

```
public class TotalCustomerFacadeImpl implements TotalCustomerFacade {

//TODO autowired or resoucre not work
    private TotalCustomerService totalCustomerService; private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOG = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(UsersFindJob.class);

    public TotalCustomerService getTotalCustomerService() {
        return totalCustomerService;
    }

    public void setTotalCustomerService(TotalCustomerService totalCustomerService) {
        this.totalCustomerService = totalCustomerService;
    }


    @Override
    public List<String> findCustomerContainingName(String firstName) {



        List<CustomerModel> customerModels;
        List<String> customerFirstNames = new ArrayList<>();
        LOG.info("***********************************");
        LOG.info("***********************************");
        LOG.info("*************************findCustomerContainingName**********");
        LOG.info("***********************************");
        LOG.info("***********************************");
        customerModels = totalCustomerService.getAllCustomersNames(firstName);
        LOG.info("***********************************");
        LOG.info("***********************************");
        LOG.info("*************************2findCustomerContainingName**********");
        LOG.info("***********************************");
        LOG.info("***********************************");


        for (int i = 0; i < customerModels.size(); i++) {


            final String fName = splitName(customerModels.get(i).getName())[0];


                customerFirstNames.add(fName);//adding first name

        }
        return customerFirstNames;


    }
```

**TotalCustomerServiceImpl**

```
public class TotalCustomerServiceImpl implements TotalCustomerService {
    private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOG = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(UsersFindJob.class);

    private TotalCustomersDao totalCustomersDao;

    public TotalCustomersDao getTotalCustomersDao() {
        return totalCustomersDao;
    }

    public void setTotalCustomersDao(TotalCustomersDao totalCustomersDao) {
        this.totalCustomersDao = totalCustomersDao;
    }
```

The error says `Bean property 'modelService' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.`

I haven't used `modelservice`.

For Dao and service class, I have true names in XML and JAVA. in IntelliJ idea when I click on XML, I can go to java class where I expect to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you have declared `parent="abstractItemDao"` for `totalCustomersDao` in your XML, on the other side you haven't implemented `AbstractItemDao` class.

In another word, your class doesn't have any modelService property which actually defined in your XML bean definition and it leads to NotWritablePropertyException for modelService

**Either** you can remove `parent="abstractItemDao"` from your `totalCustomersDao` declaration if you at all don't want to use anything from AbstractItemDao class.

```
<alias alias="totalCustomersDao" name="totalCustomersDao"/>
<bean id="totalCustomersDao"
      class="de.hybris.training.core.dao.impl.TotalCustomersDaoImpl">
    <property name="flexibleSearchService" ref="flexibleSearchService"/>
</bean>
```

**Or**

extends `AbstractItemDao` class in `TotalCustomersDaoImpl`

```
public class TotalCustomersDaoImpl extends AbstractItemDao implements TotalCustomersDao
```